# coming across with Cors issue after logged in

Tags: javascript, vuex

here is my axios get request

```
async getIpAddress ({commit}) {
    const { data: { ip } } = await axios.get("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", {responseType: "text", transformResponse: data =>
        Object.fromEntries(data.trim().split("\n").map(line => line.split("=")))
    });
    console.log(ip);
    commit('setIp', ip)
```

if request.user.is_anonymous: working fine smoothly
**console.log** is

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...   client-entry.js?d267:36 
[Quasar] Running SPA.                         auth.js?e140:216
84.54.84.225                                  client?db9c:48 
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.         client?db9c:52 
[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.                 backend.js:2237  
vue-devtools  Detected Vue v2.6.11
```

but after logged in I start struggling with cors

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
xhr.js?e38e:160 GET https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace net::ERR_FAILED
```

please help me out

Comment: authorized user's request contains additional headers, that are not allowed by the server that you are connecting to

Comment: try to remove that header (or headers) from the request prior to sending it.

Comment: @mangusta Yes you're totally right , I tried to clear those headers in `axios.get(request)`  but still no lucky 
and i tried `using fetch()`  it really worked smoothly,
thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I preferred to use this one!!!**

```
async getIpAddress ({commit}) {
    let response = await fetch("https://ipapi.co/json/");
    let data = await response.json();
    commit('setIp', data.ip) 
}
```

it worked well for my case

Comment: that's another address. did "cloudflare" work well with "fetch" too?

Comment: yes cloudflare also worked too, but `ipapi`  contains more data than cloudflare
including big amount of free limits 
that's why i chose it!

Comment: by the way I wouldn't recommend relying on third-party resource. If your goal is to retrieve client IP you may get it from inside the request on backend side

Comment: Yes you right, but i have spent my whole time to get users' ip address on backend but the result was not the real Ip address it was our ngix ip address

Comment: then nginx may get IP from request and pass it to the backend as a header or as a request parameter

Comment: @mangusta Can you show me how? now I am getting some problems with the function Above